# Line numbering in Equation

Tags: equations

I need that the line numbering in an equation would be: 1, 2, 3, ... and k (instead of default numbering 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). How can I do that?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
... \\
k
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Avoid eqnarray!](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the AMS math `\tag` command is for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\tagdots}{\tag*{$\lower.2ex\hbox{\smash\vdots}\phantom0$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
1 \\
2 \\
3 \\
\cdots \tagdots\\
k \tag{$k$}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\tag{x}` sets `x` between parentheses, and in text mode.
I've used `$k$` above to get a label looking like a math-mode letter.

Use the star-form, `\tag*` if you don't want the parentheses.

But with a narrow label, you may need some adjustments to get something neatly centred horizontally and vertically.  Here I have hidden this complexity in a new `\tagdots` command.

Comment: there's really too much space above the `\vdots` -- they should be centered vertically.  `\smash` closes up the space too much (these dots are taller than a capital letter, and they're not centered on the math axis, which is too bad); the space between (3) and (*k*) is reduced to what it would be if an "ordinary" tag were present (forced by the phantom parentheses).

Comment: @barbarabeeton, yes you are right - perhaps it would be better to write a `tagdots` command...

Comment: If you replace `\cdots` with `\makebox*{3}{\cdots}` (from the small `makebox` package), the \cdots will be centred in their column.

Comment: @Bernard, yes but I think they were just a placeholder in the OP example.

Comment: @Thruston: Maybe, maybe not…